# UICollectionView that functions like a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

The designer came back with a layout that displays information differently.

Is it possible to make my UICollectionView function like a UITableView? Where each cell takes up one row and there is only one column?

Everything I found on the net seems to be about the opposite, making a UITableView be a UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its very simple. Just make the width of the UICollectionViewCell equal to the width of the view.